# equation that may be related to number theory

Tags: number-theory

let us assume that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ are integer numbers and $m$ is an rational number. i want to choose $m$ such that the following equation is **never** satisfied :

$$(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 ) - m( y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 + y_4^2 ) =0$$

note that $m$ must belong to rational numbers . whatever $m$ get more close to 1 , it is more appropriate for my problem.

thank you

Comment: With the high number of unknowns, the solution would be cumbersome. Need this equation or with a smaller number of unknowns?

Comment: I think there should be a constraint that all $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are not $0$ at the same time

Comment: yes x and y are nonzero numbers . but my problem can never be reduced by smaller number of unknowns.

Comment: i mean x_i's and y_i's can not be all zero at the same time

Comment: For any number $m$ you can write a solution.

Comment: Oops. You are starting with $m$. Then it is always possible unless $m$ is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Four-Square Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) states that every natural number is the sum of four squares, in other words, you can solve your equation whenever you can solve $a - mb = 0$ for natural numbers $a$ and $b$. This is possible as long as $m$ is positive (assuming $0$ is not a natural number).